# Update in php using sql and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create an update form to update to the database table. I have created a function that uses sql to create the update, and a function that updates the table. I have also created the code that calls these functions. The error is that nothing is posting or changing when I press submit. It isn't running or editing or updating any of the data.

Please help me get this code working!
Thanks

```
function updateSingleValue($ID, $Name)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE faculty SET Name=$Name WHERE ID=$ID";

    $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
    $statement = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql);


    $bReturn = false;
    try 
    {
        $statement->execute();
        $bReturn = true;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $bReturn;
}

function getUpdateResults($tablename)
{
    $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

    return $ResultSet;
}


<?php

include_once 'db.php';

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $success = updateSingleValue($_POST['ID'], $_POST['Name'], $_POST['update']);
    echo $success;
    if(!$success)
    {
        echo 'Sorry, the update failed.';
    }
}

$Results = getUpdateResults('faculty');

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <label id="lblUpdate" for="update">Update</label>
            <input type="text" name="update" />
            <input type="text" name="ID" />
            <input type="text" name="Name" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

        </form>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>


        <?php
            if(isset($Results))
            {
                foreach($Results as $row)
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>';
                    echo $row['ID'];
                    echo '</td><td>';
                    echo $row['Name'];
                    echo '</td></tr>';
                }
            }
        ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: No one will review as long as you don't specify any error or issue with this.

Comment: I believe as a prepare you need to do :var not $var and then you need to bind your params to your place holders rather than just embedding them in the $sql and executing otherwise there was no point in preparing it in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, the error is that it is not posting or completing anything when I press submit. It doesn't run or update anything at all

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e noticed something with this:

```
function getUpdateResults($tablename)
{
    $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

    return $ResultSet;
}
```

try doing concatinating your tablename like this

> $t = $tablename;
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM $t";

Answer (score 1):

Please close the open connection at the end....

```
mysql_close($mysqlConnection);
```